# Multiple Tenants (Production, pre-production, integration, development) recommandations

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, architecture

I will be developing web parts (SharePoint Framework) that are going to be hosted in SharePoint Online. I can't deploy directly in the production environment. I need to develop in a development environment and deploy in integration, when everything is ok in that environment, I deploy in pre-production. When everything is ok in that environment I deploy in production.

Is there any best practices regarding the number of tenants required for this kind of scenario? Should each environment have its own Tenant?

Could I use one tenant to host multiple environments? For example, integration and pre-production in on Tenant. One problem I see is that there is only one App Catalog per Tenant. How will I be able to update a web part in the "integration/pre-production" environment so that the changes appears only in the integration site collection but not the pre-production site collection?

I'm looking for best practices or guidelines.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend one of two ways to accomplish this.

Set up a developer site in your current production tenant and develop your webparts there. This is the easiest solution. Because the webparts aren't deployed tenant-wide at this stage in the development process, they're hidden to all others.

Create an [Office 365 developer tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program). This is a time-bombed tenant but will allow you to create the webpart in an isolated environment. You will not be able to use the same credentials as your production tenant.